# SAPUI5 Mockserver issue with toUrl method

Tags: mocking, sapui5, mockserver, sap-business-application-studio

I'm setting up mockserver.js in SAP Business Application Studio.

The issue is the method sap.ui.require.toUrl is setting up the path as follows.

```
../../resources/
```

So when I add my app id...

```
_sAppPath = "n4g02.orderitemssearch/",
```

The resource is not found.... Hence I need to use relative paths as shown below...

```
//var sManifestUrl = sap.ui.require.toUrl(_sAppPath + "manifest.json"),
var sManifestUrl = "../manifest.json",
//sMetadataUrl = sap.ui.require.toUrl(_sAppPath + oMainDataSource.settings.localUri),
sMetadataUrl = "../localService/metadata.xml",
```

I would before not to have to amend mockserver.js for every app, so is there a way around this?